# How to highlight an HTML table column without using loops?

Tags: jquery, html, loops, html-table, syntax-highlighting

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th id="col-1"><input type="button" class="some" value="Company" /></th>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>Adress</th>
     <th>Zip</th>
     <th>Place</th>
     <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr class="even">
     <td headers="col-1">Some ltd</td>
     <td>some name</td>
     <td>some street</td>
     <td>some zip</td>
     <td>some town</td>
     <td>some country</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
     <td headers="col-1">Corp</td>
     <td>some name</td>
     <td>some street</td>
     <td>some zip</td>
     <td>some town</td>
     <td>some country</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Odd and even rows have different highlight classes *oddHigh* and *evenHigh*.

On click of the column header I want to highlight the column like this:

```
$(".some").live("click", function() {
   var val = $(this).closest("TH, th").attr('id'),
       col = $( "td[headers="+ val +"]" ),
       // set odd/even
       i = col.closest("TR, tr").hasClass("odd") ? "oddHigh" : "evenHigh";

   col.hasClass("colHigh") ? col.removeClass("colHigh "+i) : col.addClass("colHigh "+i);
   });
```

This highlights the whole column with *oddHigh*.

Is there a way to highlight depending on the class of the closest row WITHOUT looping through the whole selection? Or do I need to set *colOdd* to *tr.odd td...* and *colEven* to *tr.even td..* and use 2 separate statements?

Comment: I don't think you can get away without looping, however you may simplify your code using `jquery.each` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the css `:even` and `:odd` css pseudo-class selectors if your browser supports them. also

```
tr:nth-child(odd)
```

and

```
tr:nth-child(even)
```

see http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child for compatibility. (no IE 6,7,8)

Comment: yeah, I thought about this, too. But it need to cover IE7,8, so I will wait a little longer, if someone comes up with another non-loop solution. If not, you get the check. Thx so far.

Comment: in that case, maybe you can simplify by doing something like: $('input.some:nth-child(odd)').toggleClass('oddHigh'); and similar to the even class?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the `:even` and `:odd` jQuery pseudo-selectors. :D